# greatest common divisor proves

Tags: group-theory

I have two exercises for my mathematic study, and I really can't prove them:

Let $a, b$ be in $\mathbb{Z}$. Prove:

(a) If $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(a, c) = 1$ , then $\gcd(a, bc) = 1$

(b) If $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, and $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$ then $ab\mid c$

I'm trying for two days to prove these exercises, but I'm not able to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you use the Fundamental theorem of arithmetic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

**(a)**, suppose $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=1$. Suppose $\gcd(a,bc)=d\ne 1$. So there is a prime $p$ such that $p|d$. How can you use this to get a contradiction?

**(b)** Have you heard of the theorem which says, if $a|c$ and $b|c$ then $lcm(a,b)|c$? You could use that very well. Or just go with the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

**Edit**

You can also solve **(b)** using this

Suppose $a|c$ and $b|c$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$

Then, $aq=c$ and $b|aq$. And Since $\gcd(a,b)=1\ldots\ldots$?

Comment: I don't see why there is a contradiction. But I think I know the answer of (b). Because gcd(a, b) = 1, it must be true that b|q, and therefore ab|aq, hence ab|c. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. For **(a)** Suppose $p|d=\gcd(a,bc)$. Then, $p|a$ and $p|bc\Rightarrow p|b \text{ or } p|c$. i.e. $p|\gcd(a,b)$ or $p|\gcd(a,c)$. Contradiction?

Comment: Thanks mate! you're the best

Answer (score 0):

Use Bezout's identity, $ gcd(a,b)=1 \iff \exists k,s \in Z : ka +sb =1 $.

a. $\alpha a+\beta b = 1$ ,$ \gamma a + \delta c =1 $. Writing $b=\frac{1-\alpha a}{\beta}$ and $c=\frac {1- \gamma a}{\gamma} $. Taking the product $ bc = \frac{(1-\alpha a) (1-\gamma a)}{\beta \delta} $. Multiplying and taking the terms containing a to the other side.

$\therefore \beta \delta bc +(\alpha +\gamma -\alpha \gamma a)a =1 $  Thus, gcd(a,bc)=1.

b. $a|c\implies c=ka$ and $b|c \implies c=lb$. Also, $\alpha a +\beta b =1$ . Multiplying by kl gives $ kla\alpha +klb\beta =kl$. As $ kl = \frac{c^2}{ab}, \frac{kl}{c}=\frac{c}{ab}$.

$\therefore kl = \alpha cl + \beta ck \implies \frac{c}{ab}=\alpha l +\beta k \in Z $. Thus, $ab|c$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! But could you please explain a little more why βγbc+(α+β−αβa)a=1 and why kl = αcl+βck then c/ab = αl+βk ∈ Z. I understand Bezout's identity, but you're doing to many steps at once. Neverthless, thanks for the efforts

Comment: I am sorry for that I'll add the steps in an edit.